How did ALT + F4 become the shortcut for closing?
This is another in a long line of computer history trivia questions. It is very much related to this question.
How did Alt + F4 become the close keyboard shortcut? I always used that close command on Windows but found it curious that Fedora 40 also had that shortcut standard. Now I'm certain with Linux being highly customizable you can bind keyboard shortcuts to whatever you heart desires, but it was curious to me that a Linux distro would mirror the Windows shortcut like that.
Maybe there is some interesting computer history related to the Alt + F4 command that is worth recording here for prosperity.

ObRaymondChen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/one-dev-minute/one-dev-question-raymond-chen-why-altf4-closes-window

And https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180918-00/?p=99765

I had to unlearn my WordPerfect keyboard shortcuts and for a long time after switching to Windows I kept pressing F7 when I wanted to quit a program!

@ninjalj nice link. Shame comments were turned off and there was no retort about Spinal Tap keyboards going all the way up to F11.

AltF4 doesn’t come from Windows; it comes from IBM’s Common User Access (CUA), part of its Systems Application Architecture. This was implemented on IBM mainframes, and in OS/2 Presentation Manager and Windows — it’s fair to say though that it’s the latter that popularised it.
Raymond Chen explains that function keys were chosen over alphabetic keys to avoid problems with localisation and differences in keyboard layout, and “Close” was assigned F4 because that’s what was available when it came time to assign it a key.
OSF/Motif 2.0 explicitly aimed to align with CUA, so AltF4 came to Unix-style systems then (if not earlier). I don’t remember the history of AltF4 in GNOME (which is what Fedora uses), but it’s been used to close windows there for a long time — if not based explicitly on CUA, perhaps indirectly because it’s a well-known shortcut, and there’s not much reason not to use it. At the very least, since it’s well-known, it’s the safe option to use to close windows; anything else would be liable to surprise users.

Of course, Macintosh had a much friendlier one, Cmd+Q for Quit, and many Windows programs adopted that (CTRL+Q) as well.

@user8356 friendlier in languages where the word for “quit” starts with Q...

You're right, the Mac shortcut is only mnemonic in English. Windows does favor languages in which the word for "Quit" starts with "F4"   :-)

CUA was part of SAA. Also, IIRC CUA inherited F4 (and others) from common CICS usage.

@user8356 My experience has been that Alt+F4 means "close current window" and, in applications where Ctrl+W is implemented but doesn't mean "close current tab", they're synonymous, while Ctrl+Q is implemented as "quit entire application". ...and I just checked my copy of the CUA book and it agrees. Alt+F4 = Close (Closes active window). Still trying to find a mention of a standard quit whole application key combo.

OK, the CUA book makes no mention of quitting an entire application during its discussion of any of the related concepts, so I can only assume that, under OS/2, the only official way to quit an entire application is to individually Alt+F4 all its windows and the modern dynamic comes from the cross-pollination of CUA's Alt+F4, the Macintosh's Cmd+Q, and wherever Firefox got Ctrl+W from.

@ssokolow I never used OS/2, but I feel like it was less common in the old days for Windows applications to have more than one top-level window. If they had multiple windows, they would be nested in an MDI frame, and there were standard key combos for closing the active nested window (Ctrl+F4) and closing the frame/application (Alt+F4).

Legend has it that IBM had a patent on the CUA key assignments which they used to beat Microsoft over the head with at times.

It might be worth noting that the on old keyboards, function keys were arranged in a cluster on the left. On my 286, I recall ALT+F4 (and other shortcuts) being very easy to key in using only the left hand. It didn't require the hand gymnastics required on modern keyboard. (Also, Ctrl+W comes from the Macintosh (or maybe Lisa?), Cmd-Q is quit, Cmd-W is "close window").

@benrg Good point. I was probably misled by how none of the screenshots I flipped past in the CUA book showed any MDI interfaces, and none of the menus showed a "Quit" or "Exit" option, so it didn't occur to me that OS/2 might have MDI. (It has been a while since I've thought about it and only in the context of Windows 3.1.)

Do GNOME's Alt+F6/F7/F8/... to switch/move/resize windows also come from CUA, or are they its own invention?

@grawity they’re also from CUA (see the link to Raymond Chen’s post in the answer).

@ssokolow back then, an app having multiple independent windows wasn't normal. CUA embraced MDI in which you had one parent window, and possibly multiple sub-windows or tabs if you had multiple documents/objects open within the app. Then Alt-F4 would close the program, and you would use a different shortcut to either close a sub-window (Ctrl-F4 on Windows, though I'm not sure if that was in CUA) or close a document (e.g. Alt-F C for File -> Close).

Ctrl-Q is the opposite of Ctrl-S in Linux.   If you use vi and press ctrl-S to save, this is Xon so the terminal freezes.  You have to press ctrl-Q (Xoff) to release it and then type :wq

The reason Macintosh used Cmd-Q/W is because they had to. The Macintosh keyboard, like that of Lisa, had no dedicated function keys - the 1984 Mac even lacked cursor keys. If Steve Jobs had been less insistent on having the fewest possible number of keys on the keyboard, then the Mac team would probably have put window management and copy/paste onto those dedicated keys too. (Jeff Raskin’s original, text-based, Macintosh project, which later developed into the Canon Cat computer, used a small number of special system-wide function keys)

@user8356 Cmd+Q is much less user friendly. It's much easier to mispress, for example when the user presses Cmd+W to close a tab or Cmd+A to select all. The point of Alt+F4 is to make it difficult to avoid the necessity of a confirmation

Re: GNOME, early GNOME didn't have its own window manager, and recommended Enlightenment, IceWM, or WindowMaker, of which only IceWM used Alt+F4 for "close window". Then GNOME used Sawmill/Sawfish, no Alt+F4 for close, and then it used Metacity, which added Alt+F4 for close on June 2002 (https://github.com/GNOME/metacity/commit/c7a72aeed3484ab4977fdcb4245b2020469e3652), and the other CUA keybindings not much later (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78999). Other Unix/Linux WMs had been using Alt+F4 for close since much earlier.

Function keys tended to be chosen rather then Alt+letter as it was common for space on keyboards for printed function key label strips.   It also saved requests to have different shortcuts depending on the user's language.
IBM was first, and then on it was easier to copy IBM unless you had a good reason not to.
If you have only used a laptop keyboard you can fully understand how well function keys worked.

"If you have only used a laptop keyboard you can fully understand how well function keys worked." <= so true; esp. with the original IBM keyboard style where the function keys were on the left of the alphabetic keyboard, instead of the top row.

Ditto for the 10-key :D

@davidbak It's where they belong!

@Raffzahn - ABSOLUTELY! As I point out in my blog post on keyboards, here - search for "an extremely serious flaw" ...

you can fully understand how well function keys worked. <--- did you mean "can't fully understand"?

Alt-Letter is used to open menus in focused window. Like "Alt-F" for File menu, Alt-E - Edit, Alt-H Help.

@i486 Windows (and max) are relatively recent.   Even Text based menus used to be uncommon as they used up memory and it was much cheaper to ship a printed function key strip with the software then for customers to buy more memory.   Text based menus seem to have become common with 16 bit systems.
